# Upgrade to Mojave with a usb drive

Tags: mojave

I want to upgrade to Mojave but there is no room on my main disk drive to download it. Is it possible to download it to a usb drive and then upgrade the operating system on main disk drive from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier if you free space on your main drive, move the stuff to iCloud, Google drive or USB.

You would have to free some space anyway.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but will see if anyone gives a full answer to the question.